# Big O: N queen problem complexity for the code

Tags: python, time-complexity, backtracking, n-queens

I think time complexity is O(n**2), Please help me to confirm.

Basic of asymptotic notation

```
def solveNQueens(self, n):
ans = []
queens = [-1] * n
columns = [True] * n + [False]  # || col with dummy for boundary
back = [True] * n * 2  # \\ col - row
forward = [True] * n * 2  # // col + row
row = col = 0
while True:
    if columns[col] and back[col - row + n] and forward[col + row]:
        queens[row] = col
        columns[col] = back[col - row + n] = forward[col + row] = False
        row += 1
        col = 0
        if row == n:
            ans.append(['.' * q + 'Q' + '.' * (n - q - 1) for q in queens])
    else:
        if row == n or col == n:
            if row == 0:
                return ans
            row -= 1
            col = queens[row]
            columns[col] = back[col - row + n] = forward[col + row] = True
        col += 1
```

No error

Comment: `O(n**2)` seems a bit optimistic since backtracking is a type of brute force. Can the complexity even be determined without having a theory of N-queens? Maybe use `timeit` with various `n` to gain intuition.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right to use "timeit" and I do know backtracking approach followed for N-queens problem.
I was solving the question on leetcode and this approach was shared by one of the people but the approach made me rethink about time complexity. I am just ensuring if I am calculationg it correct or not.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the *how* you are calculating the complexity if you want confirmation that you are calculating it correctly.

Comment: It should be something like O(n!)

Comment: Note that if solutions to the N-queens puzzle don't exist for large N, the code doesn't halt, so the big-O of its runtime wouldn't even be defined. The code itself doesn't prove the existence of solutions. This is one reason why I suggested that it is impossible to answer the question without understanding the specifics of the problem. On the other hand, if solutions always exist and are in some sense plentiful, you might get solutions with only a polynomial amount of backtracking.